# opening page in certain position on the page when clicking a link?

Tags: hyperlink

I am trying to find a way of when a user clicks a link the page will open in a certain position on the page?

Does anyone know how to do this?

thanks.

I've tried this but it just opens the page as normal.

```
<p id="card">

content

</p>

<a href ="link.php#card">link</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `id` to `name` in the `<p>` tag:

```
<p name="card">
  content
</p>

<a href="link.php#card">link</a>
```

**EDIT BASED ON COMMENT:**

So the URL you are using is this?

```
http://localhost/ptb1/profile.php#card?id=4
```

Incorrect placement of the URL params. It should be this. Those `anchor` tags always come last. [This site](http://www.asymmetrics.com/appending-anhors-to-urls-code.asp) has a good explanation:

```
http://localhost/ptb1/profile.php?id=4#card
```

Comment: nope that doesn't work either, just to be sure i am writing my link like this. is this ok: 'http://localhost/ptb1/profile.php#card?id=4'